# Hebrew language causes troubles with figure* environment?

Tags: floats, babel, books, hebrew

I want to write a `book` document class, with the use of [`sidenotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes) and [`marginnote`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) to produce a document that resembles in appearance the [tufte-book](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex) document class.

The thing is that I am including some Hebrew language text in my project, and as I understand it now, it causes some extra difficulties.

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel} % Load Hebrew to babel

\usepackage[left=20mm,top=23.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=120mm,textheight=380mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=54mm,textheight=49\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip,asymmetric,showframe]{geometry} % Theses parameters allow enough margin notes space.
\usepackage{graphicx} % To load figures
\usepackage{marginnote,sidenotes} % As the package name says
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter{First Chapter}\label{chap:ch1}
Lorem ipsum..
\begin{figure*}%
%    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{panorama.jpg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure*}%
%
\end{document}
```

Where panorama.jpg was downloaded from [here](https://pngtree.com/freebackground/city-skyline-panorama_1198311.html).

The output looks like this:
[image]

Notice how the picture sticks to the left from the right direction.

The errors I get are
Missing \endcsname inserted.
Use of \m@^_ doesn't match its definition.
Extra \endcsname.

From what I checked it and tried the cause is the `hebrew` option in `babel` usepackage `babel`.

How can I solve this?

In case anyone asks why I get my self into this, it is because I want to make something that looks like this sine function (taken from tufte [sample book](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/blob/master/sample-book.pdf)):
[image]

Comment: First of all, is there a reason, why you would want to use the `figure*` environment in the firstplace? Your document does not seem to have two columns in the first place. Also, I saw that, independently of the warnings created by the `hebrew` option, even without it, the figures are misaligned, so the reason for this are probably somewhere else. And thirdly, I would like to point out, that the order in which you put languages into the `babel` options matter, the last one will typically be parsed as the main, try adding `main=english` to make sure, latex understands what you want.

Comment: I am quite sure that `hebrew` option causes the problem. Adding `main=english` doesn't solve the issue. I add a picture to the question explaining why I would want to use `figure*` environment, taken from the tufte-book [sample book](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/blob/master/sample-book.pdf).

Comment: You really do not want to use legacy 8-bit fonts with Hebrew. There is  technically an `ivritex` package out there that’s supposed to work with legacy `\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}`, but its author posted here years ago that people should use OpenType fonts instead.

Comment: Since you’re writing a book, not submitting a paper to one of the publishers that still only supports PDFTeX in 2021, there is no reason not to use LuaLaTeX, which supports `\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular]{babel}` and `\babelprovide[import, onchar=fonts ids]{hebrew}`. RTL support in some packages is, sadly, a bit iffy, but you might fall back on making English the main document language for the purpose of page layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your Hebrew font but you have not actually used it in your MWE, for which thank you. Further I am not inclined to download a graphic from a website with possible usage conditions. However the following MWE for those who have the Hebrew font do what I think you want (for those without the font just plug ahead ignoring any reported font problems).

```
% hebrewprob.tex  SE 591513
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel} % Load Hebrew to babel

\usepackage[left=20mm,top=23.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=120mm,textheight=380mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=54mm,textheight=49\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip,asymmetric,showframe]{geometry} % Theses parameters allow enough margin notes space.
\usepackage{graphicx} % To load figures
\usepackage{marginnote,sidenotes} % As the package name says

\usepackage{lipsum} % PW added

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter{First Chapter}\label{chap:ch1}
Lorem ipsum..

%\lipsum[1] % PW added

%\begin{figure*}% PW changed
\begin{figure}[h]%
%    \centering
%    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{panorama.jpg}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-golden}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
%\end{figure*}% PW changed
\end{figure}%
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I think that your problem is that you have used `\begin{figure*}` instead of `\begin{figure}`.

In my MWE I get the same typeset result if I comment out all the `hebrew` related code but problems with the `figure*` environment in either case. Don't use `figure*`.

[image]